# Query druid from java application

Tags: druid

I'm new to druid. I want to query a remote druid cluster from my java application. I read in the druid-user google group that we can use io.druid.client.DirectDruidClient . Can someone please help me or point out a resource with an example for the same?

Comment: Check this client library from imply: https://github.com/implydata/druid-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/imply/druid/query/ExampleMain.java

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into it.

Comment: @RamkumarVenkataraman - Thanks for the link, but the current version of druid-client library is broken and does not even build! Looks like it is not maintained actively. Refer [druid-client build failure issue](https://github.com/implydata/druid-client/issues/3)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple **Spring Boot Java Application** which queries **Druid** data using **Avatica JDBC Driver** and prints the first row from the query.

Assuming that Druid is running in local and you already have data in a table name "***druid_table***" which has a column ***sourceIP***

> FlinkDruidApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FlinkDruidApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlinkDruidApplication.class, args);
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FlinkDruidApplication");
        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataSet<Row> dbData =
                env.createInput(
                        JDBCInputFormat
                                .buildJDBCInputFormat()
                                .setDrivername("org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver")
                                .setDBUrl("jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica/")
                                .setUsername("null")
                                .setPassword("null")
                                .setQuery(
                                        "SELECT sourceIP FROM druid_table"
                                )
                                .setRowTypeInfo((RowTypeInfo) Types.ROW(Types.STRING))
                                .finish()
                );

        try {

            log.info("Printing first IP :: {} " + dbData.collect().iterator().next());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }


    }

}
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.shashank</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlinkDruid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FlinkDruid</name>
    <description>Flink Druid Connection</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-jdbc_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.calcite.avatica/avatica-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.calcite.avatica</groupId>
            <artifactId>avatica-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The native way of querying in Druid is via JSON over HTTP. They do have a Java client at https://github.com/implydata/druid-client but it does not look like it is in active development. (The last commit as of this writing was 2 years ago.) So it may not support all the features of the native JSON query language.

If you are trying to query Druid from a Java application, a better approach would be to build the JSON query in Java and then send the query over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more example of setting up and testing.

DRUID-JDBC Connection Test using a simple Java Programme :

JdbcTest.java

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class jdbcTest{    

public static void main(String args[]) {        

// Connect to /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ on your Broker.        

String url = "jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://ec2-15-206-160-168.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica/";        

Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();                
connectionProperties.setProperty("user", "vaibhav");                
connectionProperties.setProperty("password", "Qwe@2019");        
try (Connection connection = 
DriverManager.getConnection(url,connectionProperties)) {            
  try (                    
      final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();                    
      final ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select count(*) from wikipedia");            
  )            
  {                

    while (rs.next()) {                    
      // Do something                    
      System.out.println("The Count Result is=" + rs.getString(1));                
    }
  }        
}      

catch (Exception e)        
  {            
    System.out.println(e.toString());        
  }    

 }

}
```

How to use this program:

1)Create a java file named jdbcTest.java with the above content replacing the required details [HostName:PortNo,User,Password,DataSource Name ].

2)To Compile :javac JdbcTest.java
Eg.   $ javac JdbcTest.java

3. Download the Avatica JDBC driver

The driver can be downloaded from the following Imply repository:  [https://static.imply.io/support/avatica-1.12.0.jar.](https://static.imply.io/support/avatica-1.12.0.jar.%C2%A0)

Copy the jar avatica jar to your machine .

4)To Execute: java -cp .:/avatica-1.12.0.jar JdbcTest

Eg:
$ java-cp.:/Users/vaibhav/Downloads/avatica-1.12.0.jar JdbcTest
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
The Count Result is=24433

Expected Outcome: Success full execution should return the count(*) for the datasource [ in this case , my data source is wikipedia] as below :
The Count Result is=

Answer (score -1):

```java
public static void Connect() {

        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataSet<Row> dbData =
                env.createInput(
                        JDBCInputFormat
                                .buildJDBCInputFormat()
                                .setDrivername("org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver")
                                .setDBUrl("jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://hostname:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica/")
                                .setUsername("null")
                                .setPassword("null")
                                .setQuery(
                                        "SELECT __time,account,empname FROM temp where  name ='abc'"
                                )
                                .setRowTypeInfo((RowTypeInfo) Types.ROW(Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP,Types.STRING, Types.STRING))
                                .finish()
                );

        try {
            ArrayList<Row> list = (ArrayList<Row>) dbData.collect();
            System.out.println("List Size: "+list.size());
            for(Row row : list) {
                java.sql.Timestamp time = (java.sql.Timestamp) row.getField(0);
                System.out.print("Time  :" + time);
                String account = (String) row.getField(1);
                System.out.print(" Account :" + account);
                String awsregion = (String) row.getField(2);
                System.out.println(" empname :" + empname);
            }

            //System.out.println("Account:" + dbData.collect().iterator().next());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

Comment: please give more info as to why this helps solving the issue.